# Como colocar duas Tabelas em uma DataGridView?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Tenho um Programa em que queria apresentar duas tabelas da minha base de dados em uma *datagridview*, essas duas tabelas tem relação de *n para n* mas não sei como faço para conseguir ver a segunda tabela.

Paço a demonstrar o código :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                Database.DatabaseAPI.NonQuery("INSERT INTO Jogador(Id_Jogador, Nome, Idade, País, id_equipa) Values (NewID(), '" + textBox1.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "', '" + textBox2.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "', '" + textBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "', '" + comboBox1.ValueMember.ToString() + "')");
                if (textBox1.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Nome em Falta");
                    return;
                }
                if (textBox2.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Idade em Falta");
                    return;
                }
                if (textBox3.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("País em Falta");
                    return;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Dados do Jogador adicionado com sucesso!");
                DataTable dataTable = Database.DatabaseAPI.SelectDataTable("Select Id_Jogador, Nome, Idade, País, id_jogador From Jogador");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
            }
        }
```

Consegui fazer a relação das equipas em uma *combobox* mas não sei como posso fazer para quando selecionar já fique com os dados do jogador direitos.

Base de Dados :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: **Passe** o esquema das tabelas que você quer exibir para que possamos fazer uma consulta adequada para seu problema.

Comment: Tem ai a base de dados para dar mais uma ajudinha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta fazer o join com o jogador desejado trazendo as informações ligando as tabelas:

```
Select Jogador.Id_Jogador, Jogador.Nome, Jogador.Idade, Jogador.País, Jogador.id_equipa From Jogador
Join Equipa on Jogador.id_equipa = Equipa.id_Equipa
```

Comment: Agora ao tentar abrir aparece este erro: 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Ambiguous column name 'Nome'.'

Comment: Pronto. Você deve especificar no comando SQL quando faz um join, de qual tabela você vai pegar as informações do select

Comment: Obrigado já consegui.